# groupby into in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's say I have a Employee class and GetAllEmployees() return a list of Employee instances:

```
from employee in Employee.GetAllEmployees()
                                group employee by new { employee.Department, employee.Gender } into egroup
                                select new
                                {
                                    Dept = egroup.Key.Department,
                                    Gender = egroup.Key.Gender,
                                    Employees = egroup.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                                };
```

From my understanding, egroup is a key value pair, so it is fair enough to use egroup.Key, but why we don't need to write something like Employees = egroup.Value? It looks like egroup is the same thing as egroup.Value?

Comment: Because it's an `IGrouping<T>` which provides a key and is also an `IEnumerable<T>`. It *is* the group of items, which is iterable. It doesn't *have* a value, it is *is* the value.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. The documentation for [`group`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx) and [`IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) seems pretty clear to me. The latter has no `Value` property, so your claim that it does makes no sense. As noted in the previous comment, each `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` object is an enumeration of the elements in that group. What is it in the documentation that you don't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually **egroup** is not Key/Value pair, it is `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`.

`IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` represent collection of objects which share same key. Basically you can access to `Key` because it is common for all elements but you cannot directly access with somethig like this `egroup.Value`.

Anyway you can convert **egroup** into `List<T>`. In your case it will be:

```
        from employee in Employee.GetAllEmployees()
        group employee by new { employee.Department, employee.Gender } into egroup
        select new
        {
            Dept = egroup.Key.Department,
            Gender = egroup.Key.Gender,
            Employees = egroup.ToList()
        };
```

Now `Employees` are type of `List<Employee>`.

Comment: I still have a question in IGrouping<TKey, TElement>, why it is not IGrouping<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>? in my case, why it is not IGrouping<anonymousKey, IEnumerable<Employee>>. Because if it is IGrouping<anonymousKey, Employee>, it looks like each group only contains only one employee?

Comment: @grooveline I understood what is confusion. It says `IGrouping<anonymousKey, Employee>` because this is type of your group. It means that you have group of  elements type of `Employee`, not that you have key/value pair where value is single `Employee`. Same is with `List<Employee>`, it means that you have list of `Emplyee` not single employee.